# Error: lvalue required in this simple C code? (Ternary with assignment?)

Tags: c, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I have :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int a=5,b=6;
 (a>b)?b=a:b=b;    // Here is the error
 return 0;
}
```

But if I replace :

```
(a>b)?b=a:b=b;       // Error
with   
(a>b)?(b=a):(b=b);   // No-Error
```

I understand the `lvalue` is a value to which something can be assigned and how is it different from `rvalue`, but why is the `extra parenthesis` making the difference.

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language. Your question is for C.

Comment: Ya... I know that.. but the exact code behaves same in both C and C++

Comment: @DelanAzabani doesn't care to separate the two languages.  I've tried to help them, until they told me to stop.  They don't care about being accurate when it comes to c and c++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assignment has a lower precedence than the ternary operator so the line evaluates like:

```
((a>b)?b=a:b)=b;
```

use:

```
b=(a>b)?a:b;
```

Comment: -1, not true. See the wikipedia explanation at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Notes

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see it, they show `e = a < d ? a++ : a = d` being parsed like `e = ((a < d ? a++ : a) = d)` which appears to be similiar to what I have written.  Do you mean the part where it says it shouldn't be parsed?

Answer (score 21):

Actually, in C, this code

```
(a>b)?b=a:b=b;
```

is parsed by many compilers as

```
((a>b)?b=a:b)=b;
```

which is an error, as the expression `((a>b)?b=a:b)` evaluates to an *rvalue* which you try to assign with `b` which results in an error. Trying to assign an *rvalue* is an error. If it is not parsed that way, then its simply a *syntax* error. But a C compiler is NOT allowed to parse it as:

```
((a>b)?b=a:(b=b)); //not allowed to parse by C language
```

Because the grammar of C does not allow a compiler to parse the code as above.

But what you've written (the original code) is correct as C++.

Here the grammars of C and C++ differ a lot. And because of that difference you see both languages treat the expression differently. That is, `the conditional expression in C++` is **different** from `the conditional expression in C` .

Wikipedia has [very good and correct explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Notes) for this:

> *The binding of operators in C and C++
>   is specified (in the corresponding
>   Standards) by a factored language
>   grammar, rather than a precedence
>   table.* This creates some subtle
>   conflicts. For example, in C, the
>   syntax for a conditional expression
>   is:
>
> **logical-OR-expression ? expression :
>   conditional-expression**
>
> while in C++ it is:
>
> **logical-OR-expression ? expression :
>   assignment-expression**
>
> Hence, the expression:
>
> e = a < d ? a++ : a = d
>
> is parsed differently in the two
>   languages. In C, this expression is a
>   syntax error, but many compilers parse
>   it as:
>
> e = ((a < d ? a++ : a) = d)
>
> which is a semantic error, since the
>   result of the conditional-expression
>   (which might be a++) is not an lvalue.
>   In C++, it is parsed as:
>
> e = (a < d ? a++ : (a = d))
>
> which is a valid expression.

Comment: Taking back my +1 because the text you added is not true. Weird, because you should know better, given that excellent wikipedia explanation.

Comment: @Johannes: What is not true? Please be specific.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed some typos so I can upvote it again (SO says it needs an edit for the vote to be changed).

Answer (score 2):

It is really:

```
((a>b)?b=a:b)=b;
```

Note: you should simply

```
b = (a>b)?a:b;
```

Answer (score 0):

When we put an equation in parenthesis it is treated as an expression. And it returns some value which provide solution to  the error.