# Use of brackets in expression that include ternary operator

Tags: c, conditional-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Error: lvalue required in this simple C code? (Ternary with assignment?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966299/error-lvalue-required-in-this-simple-c-code-ternary-with-assignment)

In the following piece of code I got an error like "`lvalue required as left operand of assignment`". I am unable to understand why such an error is being reported. But when I am using parenthesis in the expression like `(i>j)?(k=i):(k=j)` it is not reporting an error. please explain.

```
int main() {
    int i = 2;
    int j = 9;
    int k;

    (i > j) ? k = i : k = j;
    printf("%d\n", k);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Nawaz's answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966299/error-lvalue-required-in-this-simple-c-code-ternary-with-assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that this condition can be rewritten in a better way, but your problem is observed because of the precedence of `=` and `?:` operators.

The assignment operator `?:` has higher precedence than `=`, thus the expression

```
( i > j ) ? k = i : k = j;
```

Is equivalent to

```
(( i > j ) ? k = i : k) = j;
```

Which is not correct, because you cannot assign to an expression result.

In fact, this case is similar to `(( i > j ) : i : j) = 10;` which isn't correct either.

Answer (score 3):

Without your extra ()s, I think the operator precedence is grouping it as

`((i > j) ? k = i : k) = j;`

Which obviously isn't what you want and does have lvalue issues.

Fix it with

`k = (i > j) ? i : j;`

Answer (score 1):

How about writing like this.

```
int main()
 {
   int i, j ,k;
   i = 2, j = 9;
   k = (i > j) ? i : j;

   printf("%d\n", k);
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather :

```
k = i > j ? i : j;
```