# Errors using ternary operator in c

Tags: c, gcc, operator-precedence, conditional-operator, turbo-c

I have a piece of code in C given as follows :

```
main()
{
    int a=10, b;
    a>=5 ? b=100 : b=200 ;
    printf("%d" , b);
}
```

running the code on gcc compiler in unix generates the compile-time error as 
'lvalue required as left operand of assignment' and points the error at b = 200 whereas in windows compiling using Turbo C gives 200 as output.

Can anybody please explain what exactly is happening in this case ?

Comment: Use parentheses to clarify the operator precedence you want. (And don't use Turbo C. It's over 20 years old!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068118/use-of-brackets-in-expression-that-include-ternary-operator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: lvalue required in this simple C code? (Ternary with assignment?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966299/error-lvalue-required-in-this-simple-c-code-ternary-with-assignment)

Answer (score 16):

In C the ternary operator is defined like

logical-OR-expression ? expression : **conditional-expression**

where ***conditional expression*** is defined like

```
logical-OR-expression
```

The assignment operator has a lower priority than the OR operator. Thus you have to write

```
a >= 5 ? b = 100 : ( b = 200 );
```

Otherwise the compiler consideres the expression like

```
( a >= 5 ? b = 100 :  b ) = 200;
```

As the result of the ternary operator in C is not an lvalue then the above expression is invalid and the compiler issues an error.

From the C Standard:

> the result is the **value** of the second or third operand (whichever
>   is evaluated), converted to the type described below

and footnote:

> 110) A conditional expression does not yield an lvalue.

Take into account that there is an essential difference between the operator definition in C and C++. In C++ it is defined as

logical-or-expression ? expression : **assignment-expression**

In C++ the same GCC compiles the code successfully

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a = 10, b;

    a >= 5 ? b = 100 : b = 200;

    std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it not the dup of that question? Did I close incorrectly with this?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6966331/1275169

Comment: @Blue Moon If I am not mistaken in these questions there are considered different parts of the operator. So I think they append each other.

Comment: AFAICS, it addresses the exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Blue Moon There is the same problem only in the sense that it is a problem with the ternary operator. But the operator has thre parts that deserve separate discussions.

Comment: This looks incorrect. Assignment in C is "unary-expression op assignment-expression". Therefore, "Otherwise the compiler consideres the expression like..." is incorrect. The compiler will just consider the expression as syntactical nonsense. Any sane error message like "lvalue required" is just QoI.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb If you run this statement then the compiler will issue an error like "lvalue required as left operand of assignment". So there is nothing wrong in my answer. When the compiler meets the assignment operator it expects that the left operand is lvalue. So its parses the statement like ( a >= 5 ? b = 100 :  b ) = 200;

Comment: Youhave written that the compiler considers the expression as "(...) = 200" which I interpret as meaning "according to C, the expression should be considered as (...) = 200", and this is what is wrong in the answer. Because it is not even an expression. The trailing "= 200" is unparsable.

Comment: And expectations don't guide parsing. Objective syntax and grammar rules do.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb The compiler recognized the conditional operator starting to analyze the line from the left-most token. The error message I showed in my previous comment is about the language semantic. It is not about the language syntax. When the compiler met the assignment operator it issues the error message that the left operand that was recognized is not an lvalue. So there is nothing wrong in my answer. By the way you may down-vote correct answers without writing your wrong comments.:)

Answer (score 2):

you can put it in braces for it to work.. like

```
(a>=5)?(b=100):(b=200);
```

and please assign a return type for your function `main()`

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by the syntax of the conditional-expression which is

```
logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

Therefore, the part after `:` must be able to parse `b = 200`. However, `conditional-expression` cannot parse that, because an assignment expression has less precedence - you would need to put a parenthesis around the assignment expression

```
a>=5 ? b=100 : (b=200);
```

But the fact that you need a parenthesis here does *not* mean that the expression otherwise is parsed as `(a>=5 ? b=100 : b) = 200`, it is just a compiler's internal artefact that in the error message it talks about the left operand of assignment. The C language has the following two rules for the assignment expression syntax, and the rule that matches is applied

```
conditional_expression
unary_expression '=' assignment_expression
```

This interferes with recursive descent parsers, that would simply invoke `parseConditionalExpression`, and check what token follows. Therefore some C parser implementations choose to not give a syntax error here, but parse it as though the grammar said `conditional_expression '=' ...` above, and later when inspecting the parse tree, validate that the left hand side is an lvalue. For example, the Clang source code says

```
/// Note: we diverge from the C99 grammar when parsing the assignment-expression
/// production.  C99 specifies that the LHS of an assignment operator should be
/// parsed as a unary-expression, but consistency dictates that it be a
/// conditional-expession.  In practice, the important thing here is that the
/// LHS of an assignment has to be an l-value, which productions between
/// unary-expression and conditional-expression don't produce.  Because we want
/// consistency, we parse the LHS as a conditional-expression, then check for
/// l-value-ness in semantic analysis stages.
```

And the GCC parser's source code says

```
/* ...
In GNU C we accept any conditional expression on the LHS and
diagnose the invalid lvalue rather than producing a syntax
error. */
```

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses should be around the condition in this case.

`(a>=5) ? b=100 : b=200;`  should compile correctly

`RE: K&R The C Programming Language (2nd):`

Parentheses are not necessary around the first expression of a *conditional expression*, since the precedence of `?:` is very low, **just above assignment**. (emphasis mine)  They are advisable anyway, however, since they make the condition part of the expression easier to see.

Answer (score -7):

Try this one! Because the ternary operator returns the value you have to assgin it to `b`!

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

    int a = 10, b;
    b = a >= 5 ? 100 : 200;
    printf("%d" , b);

}
```

Comment: Thanks..  but my question was about the varied response of the same code in two different compilers. Can you please elaborate this point? Thank you again :)

Comment: @Rizier123: it is not undefined.