# Ternary Conditional operator in C

Tags: c, turbo-c

`(k < m ? k++ : m = k)`

This particular expression gives compile time error saying *lvalue required*. The problem is with `k++`. Not able to understand what is wrong in this expression.

Comment: The code compiles fine for me (using g++ -Wall temp.cpp).  AFAICT it is valid C++.

Comment: See my answer at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448611/errors-using-ternary-operator-in-c/26448707#26448707

Comment: Show us the complete line involving this expression as well as the related declarations of all variables involved in the said line.

Answer (score 5):

The input

```
k < m ? k++ : m = k;
```

is parsed as

```
((k < m) ? k++ : m) = k;
```

where `k++` is an rvalue and `m` is an lvalue. So the conditional is an rvalue.

You probably mean something like

```
(k < m) ? k++ : (m = k);
```

Better use

```
if (k < m) {
    k++;
} else {
    m = k;
}
```

instead.

You can see the C precedence table e.g. here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence.

The terms "lvalue" and "rvalue" mostly mean "things that you can write left of an assignment" and "things you can *only* write on the right side of an assignment", resp. C.f. "[Are literal strings and function return values lvalues or rvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2038414/416224)".

---

An easier example to see the semantics of `?:`: *For a `uint8_t k`, what does `condition ? k : k + 1` mean?*

- Easy to see the former part `k` is an lvalue with the type `uint8_t`.
- The latter expression `k + 1` is somewhat trickier, though. Being the result of an arithmetic expression, it is an rvalue. Also it's not a `uint_8` but [`int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2280663/416224).
- The common type of `uint8_t` and `int` is `int`. So in total `condition ? k : k + 1` is an rvalue expression with the type `int`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Any links where I could learn more about precedence and lvalue, rvalue so I dont make such mistakes?

Comment: E.g. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) has a list of the operator precedences. "lvalue" and "rvalue" mostly means "things that you can write left of an assignment" and "things you can *only* write on the right side of an assignment", resp. C.f. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2038414/416224