# Error in assignment statement even when l-value given is fine in ternary operator

Tags: c, operator-precedence, conditional-operator

Consider the following C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int test = 0;
  int a= 10,b = 20;
  test ? a*2 : b*3;
  printf("a = %d, b = %d\n",(test ? a = 200 : b = 300),(test ? a =2 : b = 3));

  return 0;
}
```

When trying to compile it throws the following error.

```
file1.c:11:50: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
printf("a = %d, b = %d\n",(test ? a = 200 : b = 300),(test ? a =2 : b = 3));
                                              ^
file1.c:11:74: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
printf("a = %d, b = %d\n",(test ? a = 200 : b = 300),(test ? a =2 : b = 3));
                                                                      ^
```

I have already provided an l value as left operand for the assignment operations and besides why does it not throw an error in the line

```
test ? a*2 : b*3;
```

and it produces error only in the line

```
printf("a = %d, b = %d\n",(test ? a = 200 : b = 300),(test ? a =2 : b = 3));
```

Please explain.

Comment: provide a variable to the statement `test ? a*2 : b*3` like `result= test ? a*2 : b*3`

Comment: Please provide the expectation of your problem statement. It is not much clear what you want.

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R: That statement was merely to show it didn't throw any compile error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors using ternary operator in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448611/errors-using-ternary-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing parenthesis and the compiler thinks you mean:

`(test ? a = 200 : b) = 300`

when you actually meant:

`test ? (a = 200) : (b = 300)`

Comment: The reason is : assignment has a lower precedence than the ternary operator

Comment: @StoryTeller This discussion is being discussed [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369916/is-it-wrong-to-suggest-to-a-commenter-to-edit-my-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator(`?:`) has higher precedence(**not strictly**) as compared to assignment(`=`). So, putting assignment statement inside round brackets can have more precedence as shown:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int test = 0, ret;
  int a= 10,b = 20;
  test ? a*2 : b*3;
  printf("a = %d, b = %d\n",(test ? (a = 200) : (b = 300)), (test ? (a =2) : (b = 3)));

  return 0;
}
```

Strictly speaking, it's not the matter of **Operator precedence**, but of **language grammar**.

According to [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

> The C language standard doesn't specify operator precedence. It specifies the language grammar, and the precedence table is derived from it to simplify understanding. There is a part of the grammar that cannot be represented by a precedence table: an assignment-expression is not allowed as the right hand operand of a conditional operator, so **e = a < d ? a++ : a = d** is an expression that cannot be parsed, and therefore relative precedence of conditional and assignment operators cannot be described easily.
>
> However, many C compilers use non-standard expression grammar where ?: is designated higher precedence than =, which parses that expression as e = ( ((a < d) ? (a++) : a) = d ), which then fails to compile due to semantic constraints: ?: is never lvalue and = requires a modifiable lvalue on the left. This is the table presented on this page.

Comment: Precedence is a consequence of the grammar.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes, can be said in a nutshell!