# Double scripted array as an lvalue

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-assignment, ternary-operator, lvalue

I was wondering, how would i express it in code?

```
rand() % 2 == 0 ? map[x][y] = 'm' : map[x][y] = 'M';
```

when I compile that line in g++, it doesn't give an error. However gcc tells me I need an lvalue left of the assignment statement. I thought maybe I should give them an integer

```
int i = rand() % 2 ? .......
```

but that also gives me an error. Can someone please help? Thanks

Comment: You need some parenthesis in that expression somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966299/error-lvalue-required-in-this-simple-c-code-ternary-with-assignment))
From the accepted answer in that post, you can see in C it would evaluate as:

```
((rand() % 2 == 0) ? map[x][y] = 'm' : map[x][y]) = 'M';
```

And the statement on the left is not a proper L-value.
You could rewrite this as:

```
map[x][y] = rand() % 2 == 0 ? 'm' : 'M';
rand() % 2 == 0 ? (map[x][y] = 'm') : (map[x][y] = 'M'); // This should work in C, but I do not have gcc handy to verify
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a lvalue to use the expression the way you did. It's used for assignment like:

```
bool isFull= (candiesEaten>10) ? true : false;
```

What you wrote is:

```
 if(rand() % 2 == 0){
     =map[x][y] = 'm';
 }else{
     =map[x][y] = 'M';
 }
```

I hope you get the point. The more general format would be:

```
 lvalue= (statement)? val1 : val2;
```

and it would actually be:

```
if(statement){
    lvalue= val1;
}
else{
    lvalue= val2;
}
```